# Convert looping statement to linq mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a model object class like this

```
public class EventInterestsResponse
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int sortOrder { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public string categoryId { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using it to hold some data like this

```
 public List<EventInterestsResponse> GetEventInterests()
    {

        _data = _rh.ExecuteGetRequest();
        var yourObject = _data != null ? (List<EventInterestsResponse>)jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<EventInterestsResponse>>(_data) : null;    
        return yourObject;
    }
```

Later I want to prform some operations on this.
For example I want to check if any of the resulting objects contain a specific `categoryId` and if yes I want to print it. I have written some code and it works

```
  var InterstList = rb.GetEventInterests();
             foreach (var interest  in InterstList)
                        {
                            if (interest.categoryId == "11")
                            {

                    <strong>Branche:@interest.name</strong> 
                            }
                            if (interest.categoryId == "22")
                            {

                    <strong>Udviklingsstadie:@interest.name</strong> 
                            }
                        }
```

Now I wonder: Is this the most elegant way to do this? Maybe I don't even want to use a `foreach` loop. Can this be achieved by LINQ and using lambda expressions?

Can any one tell me how I can modify this code so that it uses LINQ and lambda expressions?

Comment: Your solution is good.It needn't linq.

Comment: I don't think you can remove the `foreach` loop, but you can reduce the looping by using `foreach (var interest in InterstList.Where(x => x.categoryId == "11" || x.categoryId == "22"))` like @brothers28's answer below, assuming there's nothing to do if `categoryId` isn't `"11"` or `"22"`.

Comment: @ekad Wouldn't it still have to enumerate the entire collection anyway though? Are you saving anything?

Comment: @Jason what I mean is, if `InterstList` contains 100 elements and only 5 of them have `categoryId` equals `11` or `22`, adding `.Where(x => x.categoryId == "11" || x.categoryId == "22"))` will make the `foreach` loop only enumerate through 5 elements instead of 100. That's just for faster performance, not replacing the `foreach` like OP asked.

Comment: @ekad Yes you are right. I will do it. But i would like to tell one more thing. there will be only one entity with categoryId == "11" and only one entity with categoryId == "22" . May be this info will help you to make an answer little more specific.

Comment: @Athul see my answer below, I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can remove the `foreach` loop, but you can use [Enumerable.Where Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter `InterstList` so the `foreach` loop will only enumerate elements of `InterstList` with `categoryId` equals `11` or `22` instead of all elements.

```
var InterstList = rb.GetEventInterests();
foreach (var interest in InterstList.Where(x => x.categoryId == "11" 
    || x.categoryId == "22"))
{
    if (interest.categoryId == "11")
    {
        <strong>Branche:@interest.name</strong> 
    }
    if (interest.categoryId == "22")
    {
        <strong>Udviklingsstadie:@interest.name</strong> 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to check whether `InterstList` contains any element with `categoryId` equals `11` or `22` first, you can use [Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (InterstList.Any(x => x.categoryId == "11" || x.categoryId == "22"))
{
    // get the list that satisfies the same condition
    var filteredList = InterstList.Where(x => x.categoryId == "11" || x.categoryId == "22");

    // get item with categoryId = "11", assuming there's only one
    EventInterestsResponse item1 = InterstList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.categoryId == "11");

    // get item with categoryId = "22", assuming there's only one
    EventInterestsResponse item2 = InterstList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.categoryId == "22");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check whether list contains anything that i need to print(satisfying the condition i explained) by lamda expression. OR May be using interestlist.contains or anything like that.So that we can avoid foreach(I have already told, there will be only one object that satisfies the condition). So it looks odd to use a for each loop

Comment: To be honest I'd rather write 2 foreaches than having to nest if structures in what is essentially a mixed foreach. Because of readability/future maintenance.  Or are there major performance boosts I'm not aware of? It would mean the interests are grouped by category ID though, not sure if that is wanted.

Comment: @Athul see the Update portion of my answer.

Comment: about your update=>
I really Appreciate  what you have done. But is it possible to get the item that satisfies the condition, inside that if statement. I am not sure how it will be coded, Can you explain it here.

Comment: yes it's possible, I have added the code inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I thing with linq you will also have to make a loop. But the linq statement would be something like this:

```
    var InterstList = rb.GetEventInterests();
    foreach (var interset in IntersetList.Where(x => x.categoryId == "11" || x.categoryId == "22")
    {
        <strong>Branche:@interest.name</strong> 
        <strong>Udviklingsstadie:@interest.name</strong> 
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to check whether list contains anything that i need to print(satisfying the condition i explained). May be interestlist.contains or  anything like that.

Comment: The code IntersetList.Where(x => x.categoryId == "11" || x.categoryId == "22") returns you a list with all intersets where the categoryId = 11 or 22...
So you just have to do the loop then (watch comment update)